# Submitting Form Data via Ajax to Google Forms on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-apps-script, mobile

I have a form on our website submitting fine through html submit to google forms to google sheets. On mobile devices it fails to submit the data, without any console problems.

I have create a new submit via ajax. This can not submit to google because of CORS.

```
var str = window.location.href

// split the string into an array of parts
var spl = str.split("/");

if (spl[3] == "prospect" || spl[3] == "nbvo" || spl[3] == "nutzungsbedingung") {
     jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
                for (i = new Date().getFullYear(); i > 1960; i--) {
                    jQuery('.anfragejahr').append(jQuery('<option />').val(i).html(i));
                }
                jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
                    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z\s]+$/i.test(value);
                }, "Nur Buchstaben und Leerzeichen erlaubt.");
                var validator = jQuery("#nbf").validate({
                    ignore: ":not(:visible)",
                    groups: {
                        dateofbirth: "entry.56657989 entry.1333766922 entry.1443399766"
                    },
                    rules: {
                        /* Vorname des Teilnehmers */
                        "entry.1208350582": {
                            required: true,
                            lettersonly: true,
                            minlength: 2
                        },
                        /* Email */
                        "entry.1875242384": {
                            required: true,
                            email: true,
                            minlength: 5
                        },
                        /* Telefon */
                        "entry.60931512": {
                            required: true,
                            digits: true,
                            minlength: 5
                        },
                        /* Email Verify */
                        "emailverify": {
                            equalTo: "#emailteilnehmer"
                        },
                        /* Geschlecht */
                        "entry.371277281": "required",
                        /* Nachname des Teilnehmers */
                        "entry.1744792810": {
                            required: true,
                            lettersonly: true,
                            minlength: 2
                        },
                        /* Datenschutz */
                        "entry.941163503": "required",
                        /* Tag */
                        "entry.1333766922": {
                            required: true
                        },
                        /* Monat */
                        "entry.56657989": {
                            required: true
                        },
                        /* Jahr */
                        "entry.1443399766": {
                            required: true,         
                        },
                        /* Vorname Erziehungsberechtigter */
                        "entry.59100331": {
                            required: true,
                            lettersonly: true,
                            minlength: 2
                        },
                        /* Nachname Erziehungsberechtigter */
                        "entry.306717187": {
                            required: true,
                            lettersonly: true,
                            minlength: 2
                        },
                        /* PLZ */
                        "entry.1654650466":  {
                            required: true,
                            digits: true,
                            maxlength: 6,
                            minlength: 4
                        },
                        /* Ort */
                        "entry.1185677222": {
                            required: true,
                            lettersonly: true
                        },
                        /* Signatur */
                        "entry.346632610": {
                            required: true,
                        },
                        /* Recaptcha */
                        "hiddenRecaptcha": {
                            required: function() {
                                if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == '') {
                            return true;
                                } else {
                            return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    messages: {
                        /* Vorname des Teilnehmers */
                        "entry.1208350582": "Vorname des Teilnehmers fehlt.",
                        /* Email */
                        "entry.1875242384": "Eine Emailadresse fehlt.",
                        /* Nachname des Teilnehmers */
                        "entry.1744792810": "Nachname des Teilnehmers fehlt.",
                        /* Geschlecht */
                        "entry.371277281": "Geschlecht fehlt.",
                        /* Telefon */
                        "entry.60931512": "Telefonnummer fehlt.",
                        /* Monat */
                        "entry.56657989": "Geburtsdatum fehlt.",
                        /* Tag */
                        "entry.1333766922": "Geburtsdatum fehlt.",
                        /* Jahr */
                        "entry.1443399766": "Geburtsdatum fehlt.",
                        /* PLZ */
                        "entry.1654650466": "Postleitzahl fehlt.",
                        /* Vorname Erziehungsberechtigter */
                        "entry.59100331": "Erziehungsberechtigter fehlt.",
                        /* Nachname Erziehungsberechtigter */
                        "entry.306717187": "Erziehungsberechtigter fehlt.",
                        /* Datenschutz */
                        "entry.941163503": "Bitte stimme unseren Datenschutzbestimmungen zu.",
                        /* Telenotfall */
                        "entry.627629727": "Notfall Telefonnummer fehlt.",
                        /* Signatur */
                        "entry.346632610": "Signatur fehlt.",
                        /* Recaptcha */
                        "hiddenRecaptcha": "Bitte das Recaptcha anklicken."
                    },
                    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                        if( (element.attr("name") == "entry.56657989" || element.attr("name") == "entry.1333766922" || element.attr("name") == "entry.1443399766") && window.innerWidth > 499 )  {
                          error.insertAfter("#dob_year");
                        } else if ( (element.attr("name") == "entry.56657989" || element.attr("name") == "entry.1333766922" || element.attr("name") == "entry.1443399766") && window.innerWidth < 500 ) {
                          error.insertAfter("#dob_year");
                        } else {
                          error.insertAfter(element);
                        }
                    },
                    submitHandler: function (form) {
                    var formData = new FormData(jQuery('#nbf')[0]);

                    // Send data to server through the Ajax call
                    // action is functionality we want to call and outputJSON is our data
                    jQuery.ajax({
                      url: 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeS-qsQeVVS8J-FhFjaYQKMCjoBNkrw5pI5nm13_451ACwZRg/formResponse',
                      data: {formData : jQuery('#nbf').serialize()},
                      type: 'POST',                   
                      async: 'true',
                      dataType: 'jsonp',
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            // This callback function will trigger before data is sent
                            var self = jQuery("#nbtestbestaetigung");
                            self.val("BITTE WARTEN");
                            self.css('opacity', '0.2');
                            self.prop("disabled", true ); // This will show ajax spinner
                        },
                        complete: function() {
                            // This callback function will trigger on data sent/received complete
                            // This will hide ajax spinner
                        },
                        success: function (result) {
                            if(result.status) {
                                jQuery('#nbpopup').show().delay(1000);
                                var timeleft = 10;
                                var downloadTimer = setInterval(function() {
                                document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + " Sekunden";
                                timeleft -= 1;
                                if(timeleft <= 0) {
                                  clearInterval(downloadTimer);
                                  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = ""
                                  }
                                }, 1000);

                                var delayInMilliseconds = 10000;

                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    document.location.reload(true);
                                }, delayInMilliseconds);                        
                            } else {
                                alert('Logon unsuccessful!'); 
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (request,error) {
                            // This callback function will trigger on unsuccessful action                
                            alert('Netzwerkfehler. Bitte nochmal versuchen!');
                        }
                    })
                    }

        });
    });
} else {}

function recaptchaCallback() {
  jQuery('#hiddenRecaptcha').valid();
};
jQuery('.closebutton').click(function() {
   validator.resetForm();
   jQuery('#nbf').find('.valid').removeClass("valid");
   jQuery('#nbf').find('.error').removeClass("error");
  });
```

Right now the form does not submit due to CORS Policy. In my other file the submitHandler just posts the formdata via simple form.submit() and it is received by the corresponding sheet.

Since the form should also submit data on mobile devices I do not know what to do.